# API get request not returning correct data in python

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests

I am trying to get data from [Uni Stats API](http://dataportal.unistats.ac.uk/) by sending a get request. Following is my code:

```
import requests
dt = requests.get(url='https://API_TOKEN@data.unistats.ac.uk/api/v4/KIS/Institution/10007856.json')
print(dt)
```

Whenever I run this code it returns me `<401 Response>` but If I try the same url `https://API_TOKEN@data.unistats.ac.uk/api/v4/KIS/Institution/10007856.json` in the Postman software it returns correct data in json format.
So I wanted to know how can I send a get request with requests which can return correct data?

Comment: It is an authorization error, you must supply this to your python request

Answer (score 0):

```
requests.get('https://data.unistats.ac.uk/api/v4/KIS/Institution/10007856.json', auth=('user', 'pass'))
```

401 is an authorization error, provide authorisation to the `request.get` method.

> Depending on your user agent, you **may** be able to include the access token in the url as in the following examples:
>
> https://accesstoken@data.unistats.ac.uk/api/v4/KIS/Institution/{ukprn}/Course/{kisCourseId}

Emphasis added.

Comment: Shouldn't the above work as I am supplying an API token. Because the same works when using in postman without providing any user or password

Comment: I have updated my answer to remove that. Try it with the `auth=` parameter. Your method that works with postman, is, according to the API specs, dependent on the user agent.